# How to communicate between javascript and react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-webview

I'm setting up a WebView in react-native within which I read an `index.html` file. The file displays in iOS but not in Android. I need a communication link which reads in Android as well.

I have tried

> javascriptenabled={true}

It doesn't work.

> react-native-webview version: 5.0.1

```
 <WebView

 source={{ uri: 'file://' + '../../ICFPackage/index.html' }}
 originWhitelist={["*"]}
 domStorageEnabled={true}
 startInLoadingState={true}
 javaScriptEnabled={true}
 allowFileAccess={true} />
```

Comment: There is no need of any native communication. You can have that html file in your react-native project and link to that will be given to webview source.

Comment: I have given the above code to a webview and included the link in the source like you said. My index.html file consists of html,css,javascript. This is the content which isn't loading.

Comment: added my index.html in android-asset in android/app/src/main/assets. The javascript isn't loading.